# How to convert char data type to date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

In a table, there is a column `BeginDate` of type `char(10)` and all the records are saved in `2020/05/06` format.

How can I change the data type to `Date`?

Comment: Tables don't have "records" they have columns and rows.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is that date 202-05-06 or 2020-06-05?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip the `/` characters and then you have the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`.:

```
TRY_CONVERT(date,REPLACE(StringDate,'/',''),112)
```

But the **real** solution is fix your design; stop storing dates as a `varchar`.

Comment: Big companies or not is no excuse @Zahra, fix the design ("big" companies should know better in all honesty).

Answer (score 2):

This might just work:

```
convert(date, mycol)
```

This is safer:

```
datefromparts(left(mycol, 4), substring(mycol, 6, 2), right(mycol, 2))
```

The latter assumes that your format is `YYYY/MM/DD` - the example you gave is ambiguous, it could also be `YYYY/DD/MM`; in that case, just invert the last two arguments to `datefromparts()`.

Comment: I wrote  {select convert(date, BeginDate) from MyTable and gives the error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: @Zahra: you can use `try_convert()` instead. But basically it looks like you have invalid data in your table...